# buffer to struct conversion

Tags: c++, serialization, struct

I'm trying to convert a string to a structure.the struct in first field stores number of chars present in second field.
Please let me know what I'm missing in this program.
I'm getting output wrongly(some big integer value)

update: Can this program be corrected to print 4 (nsize) ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct SData
{
    int nsize;
    char* str;
};

void main()
{
    void* buffer = "4ABCD";

    SData *obj = reinterpret_cast< SData*>(buffer);

    cout<<obj->nsize;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement your own string class.  You can tak a look at `std::string` and see how they do from a pointer to a `string`.

Comment: what do you expect to see?

Comment: The character ```'4'``` is not the same as the integer ```4```. Not in size nor representation.

Comment: As mentioned `4` the character and 4 the integer are different in size and value. Additionally, even if you accounted for that, the compiler could pad your structure so that there is space between adjacent data members... so there is no predictable way to do what you are trying to do. At least not the way you are attempting to do it.

Comment: How I can achieve printing 4 (nsize), can any one guide?

Comment: @Raj you need to understand language basics first, how integer and pointer is represented in memory

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is utterly wrong. First of all binary representation of integer depends on platform, ie `sizeof` of `int` and endiannes of hardware. Second, you will not be able to populate `char` pointer this way, so you need to create some marshalling code that reads bytes according to format, convert them to int and then allocate memory and copy the rest there. Simple approach with casting block of memory to your struct will not work with this structure.

Answer (score 1):

In an SData object, an integer occupies four bytes. Your buffer uses one byte. Further, a character '4' is different from a binary form of an integer 4.

Comment: It is, nonetheless, correct, and even though nobody is required to explain their vote, you're not doing anyone a favor by downvoting and walking away.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make an ASCII representation of a piece of data then , yes, you need to do serialization. This is not simply a matter of hoping that a human readable version of what you think of as the contents of a struct can simply be cast to that data. You have to choose a serialization format then either write code to do it or use an existing library.

Popular Choices:

- xml
- json
- yaml

I would use json - google for "c++ json library"